# Can I highlight specific rivers with Mapbox?

Tags: gis, mapbox, shapefile

Is it possible to highlight rivers in Mapbox?

I would like to look at the world and see a list of specific rivers standing out as if highlighted with a yellow marker on a paper map. As I zoom in, the highlights would get more precise and ultimately coincide with the actual geometry of the rivers, or at least follow a line equidistant to their banks…

Is this at all possible?

I understand I can draw anything I want at specific geographic coordinates, but I can't figure out how to extract the river geometry from Mapbox to compute the paths for my highlighter strokes…

Or perhaps this kind of thing would be easier with another provider? How do people usually handle this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is not a way to highlight specific rivers in Mapbox's water related layers by an attribute like name. However, if you are looking to filter features based on size/prominence it is possible to filter features using the "class" or "type" property on the Mapbox waterway layer. This will at least allow you to filter/style features based on their type (i.e. river, stream, canal, etc...).

An alternative approach would be to pull together spatial data outside of the Mapbox platform and then bring it into Mapbox as your own tilset or dataset. I have done this before using the [National Hydrography Dataset](https://gumroad.com/l/mapbox-handbook) (this is just for the US) when I wanted to highlight specific rivers (i.e. only show the Rio Grande, Arkansas, and Colorado Rivers). I brought the NHD into my desktop GIS application (QGIS), filtered the features to just those rivers, exported the filtered features as GeoJSON and then uploaded to Mapbox and did all the desired styling in Mapbox Studio.

Hope this helps! I have been writing a series of guides for Mapbox that you might be interested in too. Here are some links:

- [The Mapbox Developer's Handbook](https://gumroad.com/l/mapbox-handbook)
- [A Complete Guide to Sources and Layers in React and Mapbox GL JS](https://www.lostcreekdesigns.co/writing/a-complete-guide-to-sources-and-layers-in-react-and-mapbox-gl-js)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try:

1. Use [the `waterway` line layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#waterway) in the Mapbox Streets vector tileset and set a filter to show only the `river` feature type. This will show all rivers at low zoom levels, but because this is a line layer, it will not show the rivers' widths at high (close to the ground) zoom levels. Set the layer to 0 opacity at higher zoom levels so it disappears.
2. At higher zoom levels, you can use [the `water` polygon layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#waterway) in the Mapbox Streets vector tileset, but it includes oceans, rivers, lakes, ponds, reservoirs, and fountains all smashed into a simple polygon layer of undifferentiated, merged shapes:

> there is no way to filter out or highlight specific water bodies or a partial subset of them.

If you want to isolate one specific waterway (like only the Rio Grande), you will need to import that data yourself [as @tylerben suggests](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#water).

3. If you feel adventurous, you could try using [`mask` in Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs/#mask) to hide features in the `water` layer that are more than, say, ten miles from the centerline of a river from the `waterway` layer.

You can learn more about Mapbox map data in [the core tilesets documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/getting-started/mapbox-data/#mapbox-tilesets).